# How to figure out why .NET app runs at 32-bit on a 64-bit machine

Tags: .net, asp.net, 64-bit

I have a .NET app (webforms - .NET 3.5) that is running on a 64-bit server as 32-bit (I checked the IntPtr.Size result).  The compilation is set to AnyCPU so I would expect that on a 64-bit machine, the app would be run at 64-bit.  There are many Third-party programs incorporated into the app, could they be causing a problem?  How do I figure out why 64-bit compilation is not being done?

Answer (score 1):

I would check IIS to make sure that you have installed the 64-bit version.  That is what determines how the ASP.NET applications run.

32-bit on 64-bit windows
http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/13f991a5-45eb-496c-8618-2179c3753bb0.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: From my understanding, there is no such thing as 32bit IIS on 64bit Windows or 64bit IIS on 32bit Windows.

Comment: No there is. You can run 32-bit IIS using Windows on Windows.

Comment: You can run 32-bit worker processes in 64-bit windows.  That's completely different than installing the 32-bit version of IIS in 64-bit windows.  Also, @user54-64, you're right, you can't run 64-bit applications on 32-bit windows.